# Google maps api v2 customize location marker

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to customize location marker? 
I've googled a lot and find a lot manuals about markers, but nothing about default location marker.
I'm trying to make something like this:
[image]

Comment: Yes it's possible. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: see http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/, this is good tutorial.

Comment: It seems to be that everybody misunderstand me. I'm tolking about my location marker, that tiny blue circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.
Neseccery to disable build-in position listener and implement it over standart location manager.

Disabling build-in location manager:

```
mMap = mapView.getMap();
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

Implementing standart android location manager:

```
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE );
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider( criteria, true );
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
```

Inside onLocationChanged metod draw your position on map

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // draw custom marker
    MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
    mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    mp.icon(myLocationBitmap);
    mMap.addMarker(mp);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, its possible. To achieve this, first create your marker, with a longitude and latitude position. Next, you can change the default marker by doing something like:

marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_icon)));

This will allow for marker customization.

Enjoy!